# Two columned layout with multiple different height widgets, how to make widgets collapsable and keep flow of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a main page that I'm working on and that is 2 columns with equal widths, with multiple widgets on the page. The page is responsive and the number of widgets is variable. At the moment I have a solution which works quite well and doesn't use a plugin like masonry or salvattore. The reason I've gone against using these plugins is that I don't want the page to be two rigid columns, I'd like the widgets to be able to flow and fit the available space.

This brings me onto my question - I'd like to be able to collapse any of these widgets and the other widgets should flow around and fit the space left. This is a prototype of what I have so far:

http://codepen.io/charge-valtech/pen/bzJfj

This is the jquery I've written:

```
function layoutWidgets() {
  console.log('layout widgets');
  if ($(".left-widget").css("float") == "left") {
    $('.left-widget').each(function (index, value) {
      var widgetPosition = $(this).position().left;
      if (widgetPosition >= 30) {
        $(this).removeClass('left-widget').addClass('right-widget');
      }
    });
    $('.right-widget').each(function (index, value) {
      var widgetPosition = $(this).position().left;
      if (widgetPosition <= 30) {
        $(this).removeClass('right-widget').addClass('left-widget');
      }
    });
  }
}

layoutWidgets();
$(window).resize(layoutWidgets);

$('.collapse').click(function () {
  $(this).closest('.widget').toggleClass('collapsed');
});
```

But for some reason if I put the layoutWidgets function inside the click function for collapsing the widgets, it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Either put your code in a document.ready function or include it in the footer after everything is loaded.  You can't attach a click event to an element that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: That isn't the problem I'm referring to, that is just a snippet of my code, did you read the question?

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling layoutWidgets in your click function?

Comment: What I have tried is doing this: $('.collapse').click(function () {
  $(this).closest('.widget').toggleClass('collapsed');
  layoutWidgets();
});

But I think I need to loop through the widgets

Answer (score 0):

The way I've solved this is to do a for loop in my click function which should iterate through the widgets and run layoutWidgets:

```
  $('.collapse-expand').click(function () {
            $(this).closest('.dashboard-panel').toggleClass('collapsed');
            var n = 7;
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                layoutWidgets();
            }
        });
```